# Using jQuery AJAX to call a php page on form submission

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

bit of a noob so forgive me if this is a daft question.

i'm trying to use ajax to run a php script on a form submission(without refreshing the page.)

if i allow the action of the form to call the php file, everything works fine, but if i prevent the action with return: false; nothing happens.

the form is pretty simple, just a button with some hidden inputs

```
<form action = 'index.php?page=addLike' method = 'POST'>
        <input type = 'hidden' name = 'post_id' value = '$post_id'/>
        <input type = 'hidden' name = 'user_id' value = '$user_id'/>
        <input type = 'submit' value = '' class = 'likeButton'/>
    </form>";
```

the php looks like this

```
<?php

include_once "models/blogLikes_Table.class.php";
$like = new blogLikes_Table($db);

$user_id = $siteVisitor->getId();
$post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

$like->insertLike($user_id, $post_id);
```

the insertLike Function defined in the blogLikes_Class looks like this,

```
public function insertLike($user_id, $post_id){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO blogLikes (user_id, post_id, value) VALUES ( ?,?,? )";
    $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $data = array($user_id, $post_id, "1");
    $statement->execute($data);
    return $statement;
}
```

and the bit which i assume is causing me the headaches is the script, which looks like this,

```
$(".likeButton").click(function myCall() {

var request = $.ajax({
    url: "addLike.php",
    type: "GET" ,       
    data: "html"
});

request.done(function(msg) {
    alert("this works!!!!!");           
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
return false;
});
```

any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: you can change the input submit to button html tag or use (inside $(".likeButton").click(function myCall() { ) an e.preventDefault

Comment: but the php file relies on the POST variables declared in the form? unless i can tell ajax what they are, both are defined in the same file as the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the action from URL and leave it as `action=""` since you're going to use Ajax to submit the form.
2. You're setting the Ajax type to GET, if you want to POST you need to change that to POST, as below.
3. You need to get your form data using [**serializeArray()**](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/) which will encode a set of form elements as an array of names and values.
4. Change your input from `type="submit"` to `type="button"`.

**Try something like this:**

```
    var postData = $("#your_form_id").serializeArray();
    var request = $.ajax({
        url : "addLike.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : postData
    });
```

Here's a [**JSFiddle to demonstrate**](http://jsfiddle.net/occursys/ewe2k8a7/).